# How to use s skalar stored in 'let' in a where clause with '!contains' in Kusto Query Language

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, azure-analytics

I have a problem which bothers me even though i think the solution must be super simple.
I have to build a query with Kusto Query Language for my Azure Analytics log analyzer metric.

I want to make this script working for the latest app version and for the second latest app version.

This is the query code to get the latest app version as a skalar.

```
customEvents
| where client_OS contains "Android"
| summarize max(application_Version)
```

Now my understanding would be, that i could store this in a let and use it later on to get the second latest app version like this:

```
let latestVersion = customEvents
| where client_OS contains "Android"
| summarize max(application_Version);
customEvents
| where client_OS contains "Android" and application_Version !contains latestVersion
|summarize max(application_Version)
```

But unfortunately the compiler wont let me use a skalar with !contains. I have to use a string.
Is there any way for me to make string out of this, so i can use it?
Or do you have any other good way to retrieve the second highest value from application_Version column?
I created this according to how i would do it in SQL, but it seems that Kusto is a bit different.

I hope you can help me fixing this and enlighten me and enhance my Kusto skills.

Best regards,
Maverick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`latestVersion` is not a scalar. To make it scalar, you have to surround it with `toscalar(...)`.

In any case, if you want to find the top 2 items, there's a much more efficient way to do it:

```
customEvents
| where client_OS contains "Android"
| top 2 by application_Version desc
```

Comment: Unfortunately this outputs the top two of the list but with the same application version. I need only the two top values of the application version.
Like for example 2.1 and 2.0.

Comment: However, that toscalar() acutally did the trick.
So many thanks for that.